# When will Microsoft Edge v41 become a stable release?

Tags: microsoft-edge

There is a bug in v40 with textAreas that was fixed in v41; however, v41 is in preview only.  Does anyone know when it'll be officially released as a stable version?  Thanks much.

Comment: What's a more appropriate format?

Answer (score 0):

The next stable release of Edge will be when the Fall Creators update ships.